# What actually happen when we set DisableAppViews & DisableFlows to true using PnP

Tags: sharepoint-online, power-automate, pnp, powerapp, ms-flow

Most of the time when I create a new modern sites, I set DisableAppViews & DisableFlows to true, to hide the MSFlow and PowerApp buttons inside the modern UI from the end users as follow:-

```
 Connect-PnPOnline –Url https://***.sharepoint.com/sites/POS-DocumentApprovalProcess/ –Credentials (Get-Credential)
 $ctx = Get-PnPContext
 $ctx.Site.DisableAppViews = $true;
 $ctx.ExecuteQuery();
 $ctx.Site.DisableFlows = $true;
 $ctx.ExecuteQuery();
```

but even if i disable the MSFlows and AppViews, i am still able to :-

- create a MSFlow from the MS Flow app and link it to a SharePoint list
- i can login to power app and create a new power app and link it to SharePoint
- Using the site owner i can customize the list forms using power app..

so can i conclude that the above PnP will only hide the PowerApp & MSFlow from the UI, but will not prevent us from creating MS Flow and Power App for the site?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That's correct, it only disables it from the site-side, i.e. the UI. You can continue to create Power Apps and flows via their respective services.

Comment: so is this a bug? or it will stay in this way which means this is the correct behaviour from office 365 ?

Comment: This is correct behavior. It only removes the UI endpoints in the SharePoint site UI.